# convert list of map String to List of map as object List in groovy

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

i have an String object and i want to convert to List . in this list are List of maps .

String Object is :

```
def listOfmap = [[ip:'10.10.10.10',cronformat:'0 2,3,5 * * * *'],[ip:'20.20.20.20',cronformat:'0 */1 * * * *'],[ip:'30.30.30.30',cronformat:'15 * * * * *']]
```

and i used this code for convert :

```
listOfmap.eachMatch( /[\[]?([^\[\],]+)[,\]]?/ ){ a << it[ 1 ] }
```

and i want to result listOfmap[0] will be  :

```
[ip:'10.10.10.10',cronformat:'0 2,3,5 * * * *']
```

but result is :

```
listOfmap[0] = [ip:'10.10.10.10'
listOfmap[1] = cronformat:'0 2
listOfmap[2] = 3
listOfmap[2] = 5 * * * *
```

please help me . tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex instead: `[\[]?([^\[\]]+)\]]?`

**EDIT**

To include also the `[` square brackets use: `([\[]?[^\[\]]+\])`

Comment: tnx a lot . now result is -> ip:'10.10.10.10',cronformat:'0 2,3,5 * * * *' and when i used this code listOfMap.find{it['ip'] == '10.10.10.10'}?.get{'cronformat'} i get error . i think if result be [ip:'10.10.10.10',cronformat:'0 2,3,5 * * * *'] . it will be ok .

Comment: And this?: `([\[]?[^\[\]]+\])`